# How to get value of var_dump() in yii2?

Tags: yii2

```
var_dump($dataProvider);
```

throws out following output:

```
 .
 .
 .
 19 => 
        object(app\models\Bewerbungen)[219]
          private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          private '_oldAttributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
          private '_related' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          private '_errors' (yii\base\Model) => null
          private '_validators' (yii\base\Model) => null
          private '_scenario' (yii\base\Model) => string 'default' (length=7)
          private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
  private '_totalCount' (yii\data\BaseDataProvider) => int 44
  private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => null
```

I just need following value of var_dump():

```
private '_totalCount' (yii\data\BaseDataProvider) =>int 44
```

Any ideas how to pick out this value of $dataProvider. I tried witch several foreach()-loops,but I didn't succeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The private properties are not (directly) accessible but you can use the explict function for accessing properties eg:

```
$count = $dataProvider->getCount();
```

see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html